# Why is the 'this' selector not calling the selected element?

Tags: jquery, this

Apparently I don't fully understand the 'this' selector, because it is not at all working as expected.

In the html/css below I have three identical div elements each containing an identical paragraph.

The first div, which I have given a class of 'x' shows how I expected div.y to appear.
The second div, which I have given the class of 'y' is how I wrote the code originally.
The third div is not affected by the jQuery and is just there to show how the divs are styled before the jQuery.

The issue I have is I expected that because the expression is targeting all paragraphs within a specific element the 'this' selector would select those paragraphs rather than the element targeted in the parent function.

Could someone please explain to me why the jQuery for class y works and the jQuery for class x doesn't?

EDIT: I am not asking HOW to get a specific result. I am asking WHY I am getting the result that I am. I want to understand better how 'this' works.

html:

```
<div class='x'><p>Lorem</p></div>
<div class='y'><p>Lorem</p></div>
<div><p>Lorem</p></div>
```

css:

```
div {
    background-color:#658923;
    height:75px;
    width:75px;
    margin:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
p {
    width:50px;
}
.a {
    background-color:#ff5555;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.x').each(function() {
        $('p',this).each(function(){
            $(this).addClass('a').css({
            'height':$(this).outerWidth()
            });
        });
    });
    $('div.y').each(function() {
        $('p',this).addClass('a').css({
            'height':$(this).outerWidth()
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `this` is not a selector, it's a reference to a current scope

Comment: In one case, `this` references the `p`, in the other, it references the `div`.

Comment: By the way `this` can be excanged by executing `myFunction.call(otherScope)`. See also [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go through your code and `/*comment*/` what `this` refers to throughout it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // this == document
    $('div.x').each(function() {
        // this == <div class="x">
        $('p',this).each(function(){
            // this == <p>
            $(this).addClass('a').css({
                'height':$(this).outerWidth() // this == <p> **
            });
        });
    });
    $('div.y').each(function() {
        // this == <div class="y">
        $('p',this).addClass('a').css({
            'height':$(this).outerWidth() // this == <div class="y"> **
        });
    });
});
```

so in case one, you're getting the `outerWidth` of the `p`, while in case 2 you're getting the `outerWidth` of the `div`. That is why one behaves differently from the other. Fixing it depends on what you're goal is, the given code doesn't make that very obvious.

Comment: I understand that in one example 'this == <p>' and in the other 'this == "div.y"'. That was the point of adding multiple examples. What I am asking is why does 'this == "div.y"' instead of <p> in the second example.

Comment: Because you're still in the same scope. when you go into a `.each()`, `this` becomes the current element in the collection that's being iterated through.

Comment: Can you point me to where this is explained in the jQuery documentation? I cannot find, which is why I posted this in the first place.

Comment: There's an example of it here: http://api.jquery.com/each/ you'll see in the first example where `this` inside of `.each` references the li's that were selected.

Comment: Thanks. So 'this' is equal to the object that it's containing function is targeting?

Comment: Alright, I think my real issue is a lack of understanding of scope. Off to do some reading. Thanks for the help!

Comment: eh, i guess you can look at it that way. It really depends on the context though, and there are ways to change what `this` references.